# NFS MW save files

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

I used to play NFS Most Wanted back in college and recently downloaded it. It's been at least 4 years since I last played, and it was on a different computer.

But now when I opened the installed game on my laptop, I was surprised to see my saved files still present in the 'alias' section.

Is this normal?

Comment: Is this a Steam game?

Comment: @Roijan, Nope. It isn't

Comment: Maybe you are confusing the 2005 Most Wanted (only released on DVD without Cloud Sync) and the 2012 Most Wanted (released in Origin and is enabled for Cloud Sync).

Comment: @Lemon I was wondering that as well, because I couldn't think of an explanation for it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are playing the game through [Origin](https://www.origin.com/usa/en-us/store/about), the answer is that they have a 'cloud save' feature (since at least 2013):

> Does Origin support cloud saves?
>
> Yep! Origin houses your in-game progress files in the cloud so you can
>   jump into your save from any Origin-enabled computer of the same
>   platform (Mac or PC). It's also a helpful backup for locally saved
>   games, in case your hard drive decides to call in sick. Permanently.

This is why your save file was available to you even though you are playing on a different computer several years later.